# calling a function depending on if a file was modified

Tags: python, python-3.x, dependencies

I have some python (3.7) code that calls 3 functions. Let's say func1, func2, func3, and they are called in that order.

func2 runs for a long time - it takes some data from several input files, does some calculations and outputs the result to a separate file, which is then used by func3.

I want to create a condition that checks the last time the input files were modified, and if they weren't modified since the last time I executed the code, skip func2.

Edit: Note that the input files are modified separately from the python code.

I am not really sure how to create this condition. I found the module Doit that seems like it should work, but couldn't understand how to integrate it in my code.
Are there any other modules that can help me with that? Or maybe an explanation how to use Doit in this case?

Comment: What modifies the files? Could you potentially call function 2 from 1 if that is what is editing the files?

Comment: The input files are updated separately from the python code.

Comment: Your question has the `makefile` tag. Are you using a makefile? If so, then what is the name of the file made by `func2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a `os.path.getmtime` function in `os` module that returns the **time of last modification of file**. 
You can read more about it here:
 https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.getmtime

Comment: Thanks for the response. How I can compare this to the last time the function was called?

Comment: As far as I understood, you need to check if file has been modified after executing of **func1**. If so, then you can save the result of `os.path.getmtime(filename)` before executing **func1** and then before executing **func2**, you should call a `os.path.getmtime(filename)` again and compare it with saved result of previous call.